# Dropbox API 400 Error: “4xx Error (4xx) We can't find the page you're looking for.”

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am working on a PHP script that communicates with Dropbox on behalf of a user.

On my own system everything works fine. But on a certain user's system we get this really cryptic error, as such:

```
Error: DropBox API: (400) Bad input parameter: Dropbox - 4xx Error (4xx) We can't find the page you're looking for. Here are a few links that may be helpful: Home Help center Sign in Get a free account Dropbox Plus Dropbox Business message = {"ru": "..."}
```

The part in braces is a JSON string in several languages, which just displays a bunch of HTML containing links to home, sign up, etc.

This is only occurring when a large file is being uploaded, so I believe it is happening with one of the API requests like files/upload_session/start, or files/upload_session/append_v2.

Any idea what this could be coming from? I haven't seen this error before so I find it a bit confusing.

Edit: With some further testing, it is happening when I call files/upload_session/start. No parameters sent, the API reports no errors should happen on this call.

Edit 2: Here's some sample code demonstrating how the call is made. There is no data sent to files/upload_session/start. This is definitely the call that causes it to fail.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/start' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

$headers[] = 'Expect:';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->oauth_token['access_token'];
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
if ( 0 == curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
    $response = explode( "\r\n\r\n", curl_exec( $ch ), 2 );
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is giving you this? How much data are you sending in the request that gives this?

Comment: See the update in my question. It happens on files/upload_session/start. There's a lot of code so kind of hard to show, but it works on my own system just fine, as well as for many other users.

Comment: I recommend adding the code if possible. It's hard to debug without it. Also, how much data are you sending per request that fails with this error?

Comment: I'll try to dig out the applicable parts. I'm not sending any data via files/upload_session/start. I just start a new session and get the session ID, then send all my data with files/upload_session/append_v2. So this is a quite simple request. For the append requests I'm sending no more than 4 MB at a time.

Comment: I've edited my question with some sample code.

Comment: I tried that code, and `$response` contains a 200 response. A 4xx HTML page could get returned if the HTTP request itself was somehow mangled, but I'm not seeing that. You can try adding `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to see what's happening when it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this worked out. Basically since I wasn't sending a post body, that specific user's system was sending a Content-Length of -1. I'm still not sure why—not sure if it is because of the version of PHP or something else—but that's what was happening. On my own system, as well as most other users, it was handling it correctly.

So I just added:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '' );
```

And that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: With the particular call I was making, I needed to do `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{}',`